# Google BigQuery Batch Query - job state is not updating after the job finished

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jobs, information-schema

I run a google BigQuery batch query in a python script in jupyter notebook. Usually, the query takes about an hour when running in interactive mode.
Today in the morning I checked and the script still displays the job is in state `RUNNING` - after 16 hours. So I checked the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS` and there it says that the job is already in state `DONE`, there was no error in the execution and the query took about an hour (I have another one still "running" in python, which status returned an error when investigating the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS`).

So I interrupted the kernel and checked: The dataframe where I store the results is filled, so I got the results already but the state is still showing `running`.

After I explicitly asked for the job again with:

```
query_job_test = client.get_job(
    'my_job_id', location='my_location'
)
```

I got the correct state `DONE`.

What did I do wrong? How can I prevent my script from being stuck even when the job is already done?

See below for my code snippets:

Investigating `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS`:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  my_project_id.region-my_region.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
WHERE
  job_id = 'my_job_id'
```

Python script to run the batch query:

```
key_path = "../path_to_my_credentials.json"

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id,)

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    priority=bigquery.QueryPriority.BATCH
)

query = """ SELECT * from my_table """

def set_df(future):
    global df
    df= future.to_dataframe()

query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
query_job.add_done_callback(set_df)

query_job = client.get_job(
    query_job.job_id, location=query_job.location
) 


while(query_job.state != 'DONE'):
    time.sleep(60)

print(df.head())
```

UPDATE:
As a workaround I changed my script to:

```
def set_df(future):
    global df_all
    global is_done
    is_done = True
    df_all = future.to_dataframe()

while(not 'is_done' in globals()):
    time.sleep(60)

del is_done
print(df_all.head())
```

But still, for all my longer queries I run into the same issue with the state of the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the job in the while loop. Add a client.get_job inside the loop to get an updated state and it should work:

```
while(query_job.state != 'DONE'):
    time.sleep(60)
    query_job = client.get_job(
        query_job.job_id, location=query_job.location
    )
```

Comment: Great, thanks! That definetely might be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Ingar Pedersen's answer it's good to know, although the state can return 'DONE' from a finished job it can also have errors. So taking that into account:

```
while(query_job.state != 'DONE'):
    time.sleep(60)
    if query_job.errors is not None:
        raise Exception("Bigquery job failed with error {}".format(query_job.errors)) 
    query_job = client.get_job(query_job.job_id, location=query_job.location)
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#bq